# GWT: dateformat 'Wed Oct 02 00:00:00 CEST 2013' -> '2013-10-02'

Tags: gwt

I tried a ton of methods the past couple of hours but non of them seems to work. Everytime the output is the same as the input format('Wed Oct 02 00:00:00 CEST 2013').

I would appreciate if someone could give a example code of how this could be achieved.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post what you have tried already?

Comment: Can you show an example of the code you have tried so far so we can help you figure out what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateTimeFormat dateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String formattedDate = dateTimeFormat.format(new Date()); // "2013-10-03"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTimeFormat.getFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
```

You can view the information of`DateTimeFormat` [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) which includes examples, patterns, etc, on how to format / parse dates and time.